# vue событие клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть такой небольшой vue проект: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-keyboard-test-fv4yx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Смысл что есть либо поле (`search`), либо просто набор элементов (`li`), в которых должны отображаться введенные символы (`1`, `2`, `3`, ...).

Символы вводим с "виртуальной" клавиатуры (**`v-on:click`** - **работает**) или с физической ( **`v-on:keyup`** - **не работает** ).

**Код:**

```
<b-form-input v-model="search"></b-form-input>

    <ul class="show">
      <li v-bind:key="i" v-for="i in 4" :class="{on: pinLength>=i}"></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="key">
      <li>
        <span v-on:click="typePin(1)">1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span v-on:click="typePin(2)">2</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span v-on:keyup.3="typeNum(3)">3</span>
      </li>
      ....
      </li>
    </ul>
```

---

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloKey",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      pin: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    typePin(num) {
      console.log(num);
      if (this.pin.length < 4) {
        this.pin = this.pin.concat(num);
      }
      if (this.pin.length === 4) {
        ...
      }
    },
    clearPin() {
      this.pin = "";
    },
    clearCode() {
      this.code = "";
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.pin = "";
  },
  computed: {
    pinLength() {
      return this.pin.length;
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode === 51) { // клавиша 3
      console.log("S>> " + e.key);
      this.typePin(e.key);
    }
  });
}
};
</script>
```

**Вопрос:** Как ввести данные в поле формы или заполнить pin код с использованием как виртуальной, так и физической клавиатуры?!

Comment: я не понял, что работает, что не работает, и куда смотреть :)

Comment: span не ловит клавиатурные события

Comment: @Grundy, при клике --> 4 кружочка заполняются и в консоле видим что  кликнули, нужен такой же эффект при нажатии на клавиши !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что элементы не генерируют события нажатия клавиши. Его генерирует сам документ, а значит подписываться нужно на него:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'KeyZ' && (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
    alert('Отменить!')
  }
})
```

Если у Вас на странице больше нет точек, где тоже может быть ввод с клавиатуры, можете подписаться в хуке mounted(). Если же есть, придётся реагировать при фокусе. Точно не знаю, все ли элементы могут получить фокус или только элементы ввода. Если последнее, то придётся сделать искусственный фокус: клик по элементу позволяет вводить туда данные, нажатие Enter завершает ввод. Как-то так

Comment: Спасибо! Еще бы во vue это реализовать ))

Comment: А в чём проблема? В хуке mounted на обьект document кинь обработчик на событие keydown(keypress). Обработчиком будет функция обьявлена в блоке methods. И На самом элементе, на корневом тэге слушай событие onclick, которое буде устанавливать фокус. Дальше можешь наывесить анимации и т.п. по вкусу. Ничего сложного! Главное не лениться!